# Git external dir approach

Tags: git, dll, git-submodules

I'm newbie in .git.

I have my main application in **E:\Git\MyProject\MyProject.git**

Unfortunately, in order to run the project, I need some dlls located in `C:\Quali\Dll\` (fixed path in the code that I cannot modify).

The dll are also created by me using code in `E:\Git\MyProject\DllCode\`
This means that when I pull the project also `C:\Quali\Dll\` must be updated

I'm using a Windows platform and git 1.9.5

What is the best approach in this case?

Riccardo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a junction/symlink:

- https://superuser.com/questions/343074/directory-junction-vs-directory-symbolic-link

You can symlink the "external" path to point to the one in your project working tree.

Comment: `E:\Git\MyProject\DllCode\Dll` will contain all the dlls. `C:\Quali\Dll` will point to `E:\Git\MyProject\DllCode\Dll`. Is it right?